# getCurrentProfile returns always null (Facebook SDK)

Tags: android, facebook

I m working on a facebook sdk application and I have a question about profile error. When I want to fill textfield with profile.getName(), profile is always null.

```
@Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            if(profile != null){
                mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName() );
            }

        }
```

Comment: you have to initialize facebook sdk after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: already I did that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + user)
                    }
                });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,link,gender,birthday,email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Profile is loaded asynchronously so it returns null right after logging in.

Try this

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

    if(profile != null){
        mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName() );
    } else {        
        ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                this.stopTracking();
                Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);      
                mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + currentProfile.getName() );
            }
        };
        profileTracker.startTracking();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I used onCurrentProfileChanged, how can I use currentProfile onResume method?

Comment: also, currentProfile.getName returns still null :(

Comment: @OzanZaimoğlu It should be `currentProfile.getName()`. See my post edit. I'm not too sure about the `onResume` method. What is your use case? You may want to post a new question.

Comment: @OzanZaimoğlu Is `currentProfile` null or just `getName`?

Comment: I want to use onResume method for when I click the log out button, message should be dissappear

Comment: I think getName is null :S

Comment: @OzanZaimoğlu Name can be null. See the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/

Comment: It should not be null because, I used my own profile